# Including a header with code::blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

So, I've created a C project in Code::blocks. In the beginning it contains only main.c file. Then I've added a c++ class (gobject c) for dividing a project into src and include folders, then i changed extension in cpp file to c.

When I try to compile it gives me a message:

```
fatal error: /home/user/Project_name/src/A.h: No such file or directory
```

So, class name is A:

- Path for the header : include/A.h
- Path for the definition : src/A.c

Code for A.c (I've tried include "/include/A.h" and include "include/A.h" but without result)

```
#include "A.h"
```

Code for A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#endif
```

How can i solve this problem? Also I've tried to include A.h in main.c (without result :( )

Comment: -I switch to indicate where include files are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include a file in C, the C preprocessor by default can search in 2 places:

1) `#include <stdlib.h>` - the `stdlib.h` is searched for in the compiler's include search path

2) `#include "myLib.h"` - the `myLib.h` is searched for in the current directory (unless you traverse the directories)

You should try doing `#include "../include/A.h"` inside of the `src/A.c`.

Comment: Thank you, you are my savior